# Caffe Euclidean Loss Calculation over Image

Tags: c++, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

Assuming that the output of the neural network in caffe is an image of size w x h.
Assuming also that I am using batch sizes of size N.

Am I correct in assuming that the Euclidean Loss,as calculated by the standard caffe layer, sums the squared error for all w x h values, square-roots it, then averages over the batch size N?

That is, it is not averaged over the w x h values?

Thank you.

PS: Is there any way to use a math environment in stack overflow?

Answer (score 2):

According to the code, it's not averaged over the w x h values, and square-root is also not used. It's only averaged over batch size N and then divided by 2.

```
  template <typename Dtype>
  void EuclideanLossLayer<Dtype>::Forward_cpu(const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>&bottom,const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& top) {
      int count = bottom[0]->count();
      caffe_sub(count,
      bottom[0]->cpu_data(),
      bottom[1]->cpu_data(),
      diff_.mutable_cpu_data());
      Dtype dot = caffe_cpu_dot(count, diff_.cpu_data(), diff_.cpu_data());
      Dtype loss = dot / bottom[0]->num() / Dtype(2);
      top[0]->mutable_cpu_data()[0] = loss;
  }
```